# Will the program installed in a folder function properly if I remove the write permission in linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, hidden-files

I have a user account on a cluster( a server), and can only install program like python on the home folder. In case I might accidentally delete the `bin, lib, share,include` folders coming with the installation of python on the home folder. I change the permissions of the above folder like this

```
chmod -w folder
```

but I am worried when the program need to write/delete some files of the folders, it might not function because the removal of write permission. Am I right? or I the run, including write files in the folder, of a program have permissions different than the permission of user.

BTW, is there a way to hide the folders without changing the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this stop python from running all together?  For example:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir -p python/bin/
$ echo "echo 'hi'" > python/bin/python
$ python/bin/python
hi
$ chmod -x python
$ python/bin/python
bash: python/bin/python: Permission denied
```

As for your second question, no, there is no other way to selectively hide one folder without changing the name.

Edit:  re-reading, I may have mis read what you were saying about the folders.  You could always apply a "chmod -r folder" and nothing inside will be visable.  This is not hiding it, just turning off permissions to view it.

Comment: Oh, I made a fatal mistake in my question. I changed the permission by chmod -w folder, not chmod -x folder. So I can still use python, but not sure whether it will always function properly.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought you were doing something tricky with the executable on the directory. 

I think you'll wanna do "chmod -wR folder" which will operate recursively and protect all the files in that folder, not just the folder.  

I don't see how this would be an issue with Python, the files are all binaries (bin), python scripts (lib), the manual (share), and import stuff (include) and shouldn't be changing or deleting things on their own.